# EU travel restrictions, during last 3 months of UK visa

Tags: visa, schengen

I am currently on a Tier 2 visa which is expiring on 27th April 2016.

I already have a Schengen visa valid till February 14th, 2016.

My question is: Can I travel to the European Union and return to the UK in the first week of February 2016, considering by then my UK visa would be valid for less than 3 months?

Is there any special restriction on travel for the last 3 months of a UK visa?

My current passport is Valid till October 2016.

Comment: Why would you think there might be a restriction?

Comment: I Do not know. To me, it should not be. But I am not an expert.

So the idea is to get input from people, who are experts on this field.

Comment: Can you confirm whether your employer will be extending your employment? By April 2016, will you have spent 5 years or are you short of the 5 years?

Comment: @SteveThompson perhaps you can explain what you mean by 5 years, just for the sake of those who do not know.

Answer (score 1):

Your visa is valid and there are no special curtailments placed on it due to its expiry date before *its expiry date*. You will be able to travel as long as all of your travel documents are in order and you continue to meet the requirement of the visa.